# for loop dependent on previous iteration values not working

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, subset

I am writing a for loop for my dataset "identified" in which each iteration is dependent on the previous iterations.
I want it so

1. If no previous iterations have the same value in male.year as the current iteration does in male.previousyear, malerematingstatusb = 0
2. If any previous iteration has the same value in "male.year" as the current iteration does in "male.previousyear" AND that iteration also has the same value in "pair" as the current iteration does, "malerematingstatusb" = 1
3. If any previous iteration has the same value in "male.year" as the current iteration does in "male.previousyear" AND that iteration does not have the same value in "pair" as the current iteration does AND that iteration the layingdate is <= the value in the "last.seen.female" column of the current iteration, malerematingstatusb = 2
4. If any previous iteration has the same value in "male.year" as the current iteration does in "male.previousyear" AND that iteration does not have the same value in "pair" as the current iteration does AND that iteration the layingdate is > the value in the "last.seen.female" column of the current iteration, malerematingstatusb = 3

This is the code I am working with:

```
for(i in 1:length(identified$year)) {

  ifelse(
(!(identified$male.previousyear[i] %in% identified$male.year[1:i-1])), 
identified$malerematingstatusb[i] <- 0,
ifelse(
  (nrow(subset((subset(identified, identified$male.previousyear[i] == identified$male.year[1:i-1],)), identified$pair[i] == identified$pair[1:i-1],)) > 0),
  identified$malerematingstatusb[i] <- 1, 
  ifelse(
  (nrow(subset((subset((subset(identified, identified$male.previousyear[i] == identified$male.year[1:i-1],)), identified$pair[i] != identified$pair[1:i-1],)), identified$layingdate[i] <= identified$last.seen.female[1:i-1],)) > 0),
    identified$malerematingstatusb[i] <- 2, 
     ifelse(
    (nrow(subset((subset((subset(identified, identified$male.previousyear[i] == identified$male.year[1:i-1],)), identified$pair[i] != identified$pair[1:i-1],)), identified$layingdate[i] > identified$last.seen.female[1:i-1],)) > 0),
      identified$malerematingstatusb[i] <- 3,
      identified$malerematingstatusb[i] <- NA)))) }
```

It all works, except that all the values which should be 3 are also 2. This makes me think it is a problem in trying to get the code to look at previous iterations values being <= the current iteration values.
I have checked and both "layingdate" and "last.seen.female" are in numeric form.

I tried changing the signs infront of "last.seen.female" e.g. to == and != and it seems like it is just searching for the value of "layingdate"[i] in "last.seen.female"[1:i-1], but searching in all the previous iterations rather than just the ones in the subset it should be looking at. Not sure why this is.
Any help?

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps there is a much simpler solution to this than  a series of `ifelse` statements in a `for` loop. Perhaps you could post some of the data you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have mixed up the iteration numbers of two variables:

`identified$layingdate[i]` -->  `identified$layingdate[1:i-1]`

`identified$last.seen.female[1:i-1]` --> `identified$last.seen.female[i]`.

Comment: I want it so that if the "layingdate" of [i] is <= "last.seen.female" if [1:i-1] the value is 2, and if "layingdate" of [i] is > "last.seen.female", the value is 3. 

Also I have tried flipping the sign so "layingdate"[i] >= "last.seen.female"[1:i-1] and all the results still come out as 2, even though it should be the opposite function, so I feel like there must be something else wrong.
Also what does --> mean? Is it different to =>?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the answer, By losing the "subset" function and subsetting using [] instead it seems to work:

```
for(i in 1:length(identified$year)) {

  ifelse(
(!(identified$male.previousyear[i] %in% identified$male.year[1:i-1])), 
identified$malerematingstatusb[i] <- 0,
ifelse(
  (nrow(identified[(identified$male.previousyear[i] == identified$male.year[1:i-1]) & (identified$pair[i] == identified$pair[1:i-1]),]) > 0),
  identified$malerematingstatusb[i] <- 1, 
  ifelse(
  (nrow(identified[(identified$male.previousyear[i] == identified$male.year[1:i-1]) & (identified$pair[i] != identified$pair[1:i-1]) & (identified$layingdate[i] <= identified$last.seen.female[1:i-1]),]) > 0),
    identified$malerematingstatusb[i] <- 2, 
     ifelse(
    (nrow(identified[(identified$male.previousyear[i] == identified$male.year[1:i-1]) & (identified$pair[i] != identified$pair[1:i-1]) & (identified$layingdate[i] > identified$last.seen.female[1:i-1]),]) > 0),
      identified$malerematingstatusb[i] <- 3,
      identified$malerematingstatusb[i] <- NA)))) }
```